# Fast way to integrate $\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} dx \,dy$ in unit square

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I am looking for a fast way to integrate $$ \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} dx \,dy$$ using standard techniques ( no complex analysis and no functional analysis).

I am aware that wolframalpha spits out a solution, but this one is quite long, I assume that there is a faster way to do this. The result will be $\frac{\pm \pi}{2}$(depending on which integral you do first). By the way: Please be aware of the fact, that fubini's theorem does not hold in this case.

Comment: Did you try to use polar coordinates?

Comment: since fubini's theorem does not hold, I have doubts that it is legitimate to use polar coordinates

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini's_theorem#Rearranging_a_conditionally_convergent_iterated_integral?

Comment: In case people may be reading this who don't understand why Fubini's theorem doesn't apply: Fubini's theorem applies when $\displaystyle\iint\limits_{[a,b]\times[c,d]} |f(x,y)|\,d(x,y)<\infty$.  In this case, the integral of the absolute value is infinite.  Maybe (or maybe not?) the quickest way to see that it's infinite in this case is to observe that these two iterated integrals differ in value.

Answer (score 4):

I played around a little and eventually realized that 
$${d \over dx} {x \over x^2 + y^2} = -{x^2 - y^2 \over (x^2 + y^2)^2}$$
So the inner integral is just
$$-{1 \over 1 + y^2}$$
Integrating this from $0$ to $1$ gives you ${\displaystyle - {\pi \over 4}}$. Doing a similar argument when doing the $y$ integral first gives ${\displaystyle {\pi \over 4}}$.

Answer (score 3):

Start with the inside integral:
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} dx
$$
Let $x=y\tan\theta$, so that $dx = y\sec^2\theta\,d\theta$ and $x^2+y^2 = y^2\tan^2\theta+y^2 = y^2\sec^2\theta$.  As $x$ goes from $0$ to $1$, $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $\arctan(1/y)$, so the integral becomes
\begin{align}
& \phantom{={}}\int_0^{\arctan(1/y)} \frac{y^2\tan^2\theta-y^2}{(y^2\tan^2\theta+y^2)^2} y\sec^2\theta\,d\theta \\[12pt]
& = \frac1y\int_0^{\arctan(1/y)} \frac{\tan^2\theta-1}{\sec^4\theta}\sec^2\theta\,d\theta \\[12pt]
& =\frac1y\int_0^{\arctan(1/y)}(\sin^2\theta-\cos^2\theta)\,d\theta \\[12pt]
& = \frac1y\int_0^{\arctan(1/y)} -\cos(2\theta)\,d\theta \\[12pt]
& = \frac1y\left[\frac{-\sin(2\theta)}{2}\right]_{\theta=0}^{\theta=\arctan(1/y)} = \frac1y\left[-\sin\theta\cos\theta\right]_{\theta=0}^{\theta=\arctan(1/y)}. \tag 1
\end{align}

Since tangent${}={}$opposite$/$adjacent, draw a right triangle in which the "opposite" side is $1$ and the "adjacent" side is $y$.  By the Pythagorean theorem, the hypotenuse is $\sqrt{1+y^2}$, so the sine is opposite$/$hypotenuse $=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}$ and the cosine is adjacent$/$hypotenuse $=\dfrac{y}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}$.  Hence $(1)$ becomes
$$
\frac{-1}{1+y^2}.
$$

It's easy to integrate *that* from $0$ to $1$.